# How can I set up a reverse DNS for a private subnet using route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have websites running in a private subnet that communicates to the outside world using NAT.

Our mails are going straight to spam folder, even though AWS has unlocked our full account.

How do you create a reverse dns for our website using route 53?  Do we have to use the nat ip address?

Thanks!

Edit: What goes into "Name", "Type", "Alias", "TTLS", and "Value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Elastic IP for your NAT gateway, you can ask AWS to set a reverse record for you. [Just fill out this form.](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request)

There may be other reasons why your emails are marked as spam. Check your EIP via http://multirbl.valli.org to see who may be blacklisting you.

Comment: You're correct on how to set up the R/DNS config -- that is indeed the *only* way it is done in AWS -- but if mails are showing up in a "spam folder" they may be getting classified as spam heuristically, due to lack of SPF, DKIM, TLS, a proper MX record for the domain, etc., etc... not a blacklist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I have no idea HOW to set up a reverse DNS, and when I googled it, it was rather lack luster as to how to actually do it.  What goes into "Name", "Type", "Alias", "TTLS", "Value"

Comment: For EC2, you get a reverse DNS for your NAT's public IP (Elastic IP) by filling out the form that I linked in my answer. You cannot do it in Route 53 as you do not control the zone that your EIP is in. Michael's comment is important in your case: your traffic is almost certainly not being marked as spam due to a missing or incorrect reverse DNS record. Making sure you have SPF and DKIM records set up and checking your emails with a scanner (I use SpamAssassin myself) may bear more fruit. You may instead want to look into using SES (and configuring SPF/DKIM for it).

Comment: @AllenLuce And this is why its so confusing.  I have messages from AWS support center telling me to set up a reverse DNS ... >.<

Comment: Please feel free to share the message, the details may help to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use the EIP of the NAT Gateway.

However, that is probably not going to be enough. There are a number of reasons that email servers decide that email is SPAM.

This AWS document will help you understand the processes and solutions. This document is for Amazon SES but the principles are the same.

[Amazon SES and Deliverability](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/deliverability-and-ses.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I have no idea HOW to set up a reverse DNS, and when I googled it, it was rather lack luster as to how to actually do it. What goes into "Name", "Type", "Alias", "TTLS", "Value"